# Use of yes i do in if you want sentence

Tags: sentence

If somebody says "if you want to eat this let me know"

Second person replies "yes i do"

Does "yes i do" here means "yes i want to eat this"?

Is this a correct sentence?

Comment: Conversation is more more fluid and flexible than written language. It's not common/idiomatic to reply "*yes, I do*" to "*if you want to..*", but it's not wrong, either. It is very common to reply "*yes I do*" to "*do you want to ...?*". And of course it means the person "*wants to eat this*"; there is zero room for ambiguity.  BTW, they're *really* good at explaining the subtleties and nuances of language like this at our sister site, [ELL.se].

Comment: The "literal" affirmative response would be *Yes, I **will*** [let you know **if** I want it], which allows for the possibility that you don't yet *know* (or aren't willing to say) whether you will want it or not when the time comes. Saying *Yes, I **do*** simply steps forward in time and assumes you're being offered something to eat right now, rather than simply being offered the chance to make a choice later.

Comment: Thank you for the answers they were really helpful.  If the question becomes " if you REALLY want to eat this" .. Then what should be the answer " Yes i do" will also be correct or the answer should be "Yess i Really do" ?

Answer (score 1):

The question asked here requires a positive or negative response. The positive response being someone letting you know that they want to eat it and the negative response being someone not wanting to eat it. So when the response is "yes I do" it is a positive response therefore you can safely conclude that they want to eat it. And YES the response it is correct under the rules of "spoken English".

Comment: Thank you for the answers they were really helpful. If the question becomes " if you REALLY want to eat this" .. Then what should be the answer " Yes i do" will also be correct or the answer should be "Yess i Really do" ?